# Jittery / laggy UI updates while dragging UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, drag, nsrunloop

I have a `UIScrollView` that I use purely for it's `contentOffset`. As the `contentOffset` changes, my subview's are moved around according to a simple math function. Mostly, this entails having their y positions adjusted, but not linearly with respect to the `UIScrollView`'s `contentOffset.y`.

An example of adjusting the yPosition could be something like this:

```
CGRect newFrame = subview.frame;
newFrame.origin.y = log(scrollView.contentOffset.y) + 300;
[subview setFrame:newFrame];
```

Everything works fine in the simulator and works great on a device while the `UIScrollView` isn't receiving touches (~24-30fps), but while the user is touching the screen and dragging, the fps drops to ~3-5fps. Between dragging and not, there shouldn't be any difference, except in the run loop, potentially. To adjust for that, I've even tried this in `scrollViewDidScroll:`

```
[self performSelector:@selector(updateCards) onThread:[NSThread mainThread] withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES modes:@[NSRunLoopCommonModes, UITrackingRunLoopMode]];
```

and variations, but with no effect.

Is there a reason for the fps drop off and is there something that I can do to fix this issue? I am using an iPod 5th Generation for most of these tests.

Comment: Can you include some code? Specifically, I assume your making calls from -scrollViewDidScroll:. Also, which devices are you testing on? I've seen behaviors like this iPod 4 and older if you're using retina-resolution graphics.

Comment: @Ryan I've updated the question to include code and the device.

Comment: Where are you calling that from? More context will help!

Comment: Can you try adjusting *center* instead of *frame*?

Comment: @Ryan I'm calling that from updateCards, which is called from scrollViewDidScroll. I'll update the question, as well.

Comment: @nielsbot Setting `center` instead of `frame` doesn't seem to help. The performance still drops off.

Comment: The center/frame shouldn't make a noticeable difference. And you don't need to perform the selector on a separate thread. Just try calling -updateCards directly. The only things I can think of are either you have many views, or those views are very complicated. When you call [subview setFrame:], that makes subsequent calls like -layoutSubviews for each card. Are those intensive operations? Can you try this with all your cards as simple UIViews? Can you try this with 1 or 2 cards?

Comment: @Ryan This happens with 1 or 2 cards, but only while the user is dragging. The views have 5 UILabels and that's all, so I'm hoping they aren't very intensive. At most, there would be 6.

Comment: Strange. I'd love to help more, but really need more context. If you want to send me some sample code (or the project), email it to ryan [at] romotive [dot] com.

Comment: @Ryan Well, thank you for the help. Unfortunately I can't disclose anything further, but I do appreciate everything thus far.

Comment: I understand. One last thing to try is newFrame.origin.y = scrollView.contentOffset.y. Make sure your math isn't producing some weird optical illusion! Also, make sure your cards aren't inside the scroll view.

Comment: what about applying a translate transform instead of setting the frame?

Comment: Is the background color of the labels `clearColor`? If so, set it to match the background of their parent view and mark the labels as `opaque`.